# Is indexeddb native supported on safari 7.1?

Tags: javascript, safari, native, indexeddb

there are already lots of questions relating to Safari and indexeddb.
From "can i use it" http://caniuse.com/indexeddb is still the old state.
but according to this link
http://html5test.com/s/0033c01c6c2f5c0f.html
indexeddb should be fully supported by Safari.
rumors are telling that the Safari 7.1.1 is out there.

Can someone confirm if the indexeddb is supported now by the current Version 7.1.1 of Safari?

best thanks

Comment: The only evidence we have is what you have.

Comment: NDA prevent telling anything publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the current update in 
http://caniuse.com/indexeddb the IndexedDB should be supported in Safari 8.0, so it is definitive a good choice to go with IndexedDB instead of WebSQL, currently i am using https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim to fill the gap for Safari and Android Browsers.